# Term-wise expectation of the Taylor series for $1/X$ yields asymptotic expansion for $\mathsf EX^{-1}$. What are the conditions?

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Migrated to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426603/term-wise-expectation-of-the-taylor-series-for-1-x-yields-asymptotic-expansion).

Let $X\sim F_X$ denote a continuous random variable. Computing the first negative moment $\mathsf EX^{-1}$ (assuming it exists) may not be tractable and thus a common tactic is to "approximate" it via Taylor series. Expanding $1/X$ about $\mathsf EX=\mu$ and then evaluating the expected value of the resulting series term-wise yields the formal expression
$$
\tag{1}
\mathsf EX^{-1}=\frac{1}{\mu}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-\mu)^{-k}\mathsf E(X-\mu)^k.
$$
Typically one uses only the first one or two terms of this series as the approximation to the expected value.

In many cases, the support of $X$ will lie outside the interval of convergence for the series expansion of $1/X$, which happens to be $X\in(0,2\mu)$, leading to the series in $(1)$ being a divergent asymptotic expansion for $\mathsf EX^{-1}$. My question is if we can put general conditions under which such series are asymptotic. Specifically, could we replace the $?\to ?$ in
$$
\mathsf EX^{-1}\sim\frac{1}{\mu}\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-\mu)^{-k}\mathsf E(X-\mu)^k,\quad\text{as}\quad ?\to ?
$$
with $\mathsf P(X\in (0,2\mu))\to 1$?

**(Simple) Example:**

If $X\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ is a gamma random variable parameterized in terms of a shape $\alpha$ and rate $\beta$ then
$$
\tag{2}
\mathsf EX^{-1}=\frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}.
$$
Since $\operatorname{supp}(X)=(0,\infty)$ we expect $(1)$ to yield an asymptotic expansion for $(2)$. Substituting the appropriate moments into $(1)$ yields
$$
\tag{3}
\mathsf EX^{-1}\sim\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^\infty{_2F}_0\left({-k,\alpha\atop -};\frac{1}{\alpha}\right).
$$
As $\alpha\to\infty$, we see $\mathsf EX^{-1}\sim\beta/\alpha$, which is the first term of $(3)$. Since $\alpha\to\infty$ implies $\mathsf P(X\in(0,2\alpha/\beta))\to 1$ it would seem appropriate to write
$$
\tag{3}
\mathsf EX^{-1}\sim\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^\infty{_2F}_0\left({-k,\alpha\atop -};\frac{1}{\alpha}\right),\quad \mathsf P(X\in(0,2\alpha/\beta))\to 1.
$$

Comment: One more nice problem ! Are you OK ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks stranger!